# Has_many of different models association in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations, rails-migrations

I have a few different models which I would like to add multiple images to.

I have an image model with `belongs_to` associations set up to the different owning models (each of these owning models has `has_many :images` defined).

I would like to know what's the appropriate migration I should create in order to add an `image_ids` column to each of owning models.

I assume something like this...

`rails g migration AddImagesToBusinesses images businesses image_ids:integer`

However, I'm confused as I believe that you can only make one association this way and it would need to be completed by adding a column to the images table to identify the id of the model it belongs to (here there are a few different models).

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you concern about relationship of image to other model. You should try polymorphic associations like this.

**Generate the Image model:**

```
class CreateImages < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :images do |t|
      t.string :file_id
      t.boolean :featured
      t.references :imageable, polymorphic: true, index: true
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

**Update the Image model:**

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  attachment :file
  belongs_to :imageable, polymorphic: true
end
```

**Add association to other models like this**

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :images, as: :imageable, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_attachments_for :images, attachment: :file
end
```

For more details you [Ruby on Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations).

Comment: Ok cool thanks! I had seen these but was unsure that they applied here.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need Polymorphic associations.
See [documentaions](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations) here.